# Pytest asyncio not launching simple async test

Tags: python, asynchronous, pytest

Using Pytest and asyncio I am trying to execute an async test:

```
async def count(self):
    return "2"

async def test_foo(self):
    x = []
    x.append(await asyncio.gather(self.count(), self.count(), self.count()))
    print(x)
```

If this code is launched without using pytest, it returns this:

```
[['2', '2', '2']]
```

With Pytest it does not seem to be executing anything inside the funcion. It returns this warning:

```
 RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TestClass.test_foo' was never awaited
    method()
```

Any idea?

Comment: you need to use a plug-in to inject the event loop in to your test functions, specifically this one —> https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pytest.mark.asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/) marker.

> Mark your test coroutine with this marker and pytest will execute it as an asyncio task using the event loop provided by the event_loop fixture.

E.g.

```py
import asyncio
import pytest


class TestClass:
    async def count(self):
        return "2"

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_foo(self):
        x = []
        x.append(await asyncio.gather(self.count(), self.count(), self.count()))
        print(x)
        assert x == [['2', '2', '2']]
```

unit test result:

```
⚡  coverage run -m pytest -s /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66546652/test_example.py && coverage report -m --include="src/*"
============================================================================================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.2, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab
plugins: asyncio-0.10.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

src/stackoverflow/66546652/test_example.py [['2', '2', '2']]
.

============================================================================================================================================= 1 passed in 0.03s =============================================================================================================================================
Name                                         Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66546652/test_example.py      11      0   100%
```